# Can we use EF migrations with MySql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations

Is there a way to use EntityFramework 4.3 beta with migrations with MySql database? Can we use migrations with MySql Database? Is it possible to use incremental database development with EF code first without me touching the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically yes. Practically you first need to get (or create yourselves) class derived from `System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql.MigrationSqlGenerator` which will be responsible for generating SQL for MySQL. [Here](http://romiller.com/2012/01/16/customizing-code-first-migrations-provider/) is more about customizing (or rewriting) SQL generation.

You can also wait until developers of EF supporting ADO.NET providers include this feature to their packages. For example [Devart already started work on their migrations support](http://www.devart.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=22780&sid=e4cda7dbe37f317fc646ebe0c2f29be2) for thier Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL and SQLite.

Comment: The support for Entity Framework Code First Migrations was added in the new versions of Devart dotConnect ADO.NET providers for Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite : http://www.devart.com/news/2012/dotconnects670.html .

Comment: thanks @Ladislav-mrnka.. I tried customizing but every time I get a new error.. May be I'll try devart..